# Lua: Replacing occurrences of specific words in a string

Tags: regex, string, lua

I want to replace all occurrences of **abc** in my string to **xyz** as below:

**The following must be replacd with xyz:**

`abc` with space in either side `,abc` `abc,` `abc;` `abc.`

**But the following must be left unchanged:**

`abc` as part of any other word like `aabcd` or `abcdef` 
`abc`having _ after or before it like `abc_` or `_abc`

I tried the following codes but didn't work out:

```
string.gsub(str,'%W'.."abc"..'%W', "xyz")
```

or

```
string.gsub(str,'[ ,]'.."abc"..'[ ,.;]', "xyz")
```

is t possible to do so in lua? May you please guide me? regards

Comment: `string.gsub(str, "%f[%w]".."abc".."%f[%W]", "xyz")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thank you, you've put me in right direction :)

Comment: Sorry, it should be `string.gsub(str, "%f[%w_]".."abc".."%f[^%w_]", "xyz")` to work correctly with underscores.

Comment: Thank you :) how can I mark your comment as answer?